# Unable to filter out records using C# list in Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm having a Products table in my database and it's having a string column for saving colour of products.

I'm trying to implement a functionality where user can search products by selecting multiple colour names. For this, I'm using a C# List that contains multiple colour names.

```
List<string> colorNames = new List<string>() { "silver" };
```

The above code shows that I'm currently using only one colour to find products matching 'silver' colour. The Linq query that I've used is below:

```
context.Products.Where(prd => colorNames.Contains(prd.Color.ToLower().Trim()));
```

The above code runs without any error but problem that I'm facing is that it's returning products that are having silver colour only. But in the database there are also existing products having colours like **'Light Silver'**, **'Dark Silver Red'** etc. I want my Linq query to return these products also.

I know that it's not possible as the query will match only silver colour but I need a workaround to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Products.Where(prd => colorNames.Any(col => prd.Color.ToLower().Trim().Contains(col)));
```

You can give this a go